# Master element attribute? (or technique)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way you can set an element to be a master and have all other elements on a page appear and behave in exactly the same, same style, same code, same attributes, same values?

```
<input id="btnBack" name="btnBack" type="button" value="Back" disabled="disabled" style="margin-right: 10px" />
$('#btnBack').click(...do stuff);

<input master="btnBack" />
```

Or failing this is there any technique to concisely achieve the same result?

I'm half expecting there to be a Javascript library out there that copies all the attributes.

Comment: you might be able to do something with a javascript function that applies everything for you like that. But I don't think there's anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

Same style = css

Same attributes, values, etc = JS

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqadz/) for an example to get you started or this code snippet...

The CSS

```
 input {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
 }
```

The JS

```
var value = 'myval';
var disabled = 'disabled';

var myElements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++){
    myElements[i].value = value;
    myElements[i].disabled = disabled;
    }
```

Comment: Or you could post your answer here, in the actual *answer* to the question. That way, when JS Fiddle next falls over, this 'answer' doesn't become immediately useless.

Comment: Personally I like jsFiddle, sometimes too much code can put people off from reading the question. However, it is a dependency and that is exactly what I'm trying to remove from my code, hence my question.  I'll update the question with answer and fiddle!

Comment: This answer is along the right tracks but it is not generic enough, maybe there is a function out there or a library that I can link to and it will just do the work.  I'll write one if not!

Answer (score 0):

Yes with CSS classes. Create a master class and then use the class="master" on all your elements.

However I think you'll find you don't really want to do this once you get into it. But it will be easy to change the class on the elements you want to change so it won't hurt you to get started this way.

You can read about CSS here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/ though there are better resources w3schools covers a lot of ground.

If you're interested in building a consistent feel to a site and don't mind using jquery (which I love!) then you should checkout the jquery UI themeroller:
http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Comment: Thanks for your input but this will only work for the style not the attributes (type, id, value etc).  Maybe there is a jquery add-in or a javascript library???

Comment: jquery has some amazing selectors to accomplish these things:
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're referring to, but best bet is use a class on all the elements you want to style and behave the same.

E.g.

```
File: index.html
<a href="#" class="master-class">Awesome Link</a>
<button class="master-class">Awesome Button</a>

File: style.css
.master-class {
   color: black;
   background: white;
   more of your styles...
}

File: scripts.js
$(function() {
  $(".master-class").click(function() {
    alert("This is from one of the many elements with the class 'master-class'");
  });
});
```

Team Treehouse is a great place to really learn all about everything web. I've been using them for a while even though I knew most of the stuff on there, but I always pick up a few new things. http://teamtreehouse.com/

W3Schools ( http://www.w3schools.com ) is also great. It's where I learnt a lot of stuff in the beginning.

There is also a large amount of podcasts and vodcasts out there to teach you too, just search iTunes for web design.

Comment: Thanks for your input but this will only work for the style not the attributes (type, id, value etc). Maybe there is a jquery add-in or a javascript library???

Comment: Then you can set the attributes via jQuery as well.

`$(".master-class").attr('type', 'submit')`

You won't want to set the same ID on multiple elements though. An ID has to be unique to each page that it's used on. Trust me, the times I've accidentally used an ID twice or multiple times has ended in hours of debugging.

Comment: Thanks Jack, yup I think that's the way.  I'm actually using asp.net MVC and am thinking of just creating some partial pages for each button, passing in a unique id as the model and adding those ids to the jquery tags.